# JavaFX pagination: rename tabs and set reachability

Tags: pagination, javafx-2

I have a pagination and I have 2 problems:
1. How can I set Names for the single tabs?
2. How can I set single pages reachable / unreachable?

Answer (score 0):

Did you see Ensemble example for Pagination?

If you don't know what Ensemble is, download it here (section "JavaFX Demos and Samples Downloads"):
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Comment: Ah, you are right. Unfortunately it`s just the sample from the oracle-tutorial. The tabs are not named and all pages are reachable.